# How do i make a java script that activates a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know how i can make a javascript that pushes a button on a website. I have tried to search the forum but nothing i have found is working. the button i am trying to make the script for is:`<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="1" data-upper="7"><span> 1 to 7</span><span></span></button>` it is located under 7 "div"

Comment: If you want to automate driving a web site you can use something like selenium web driver

Comment: Do you want to actually push the button or just run the code that is connected to the button's click event?

Comment: Scott Marcus, i only want to run the code activated by the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="myButton" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="1" data-upper="7" onclick="alert('hello');"><span> 1 to 7</span><span></span>
    </button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('myButton').click();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```